# Performance between thread local and stack allocated variable

Tags: c++, c, performance, gcc, thread-local

```
static const char* objToStr(Obj o)
{
    static __thread char s[64];
    snprintf(s, sizeof(s), "Obj: ...", ...);
    return s;
}

static const char* objToStr2(Obj o, char* s, size_t len)
{
    snprintf(s, len, "Obj: ...", ...);
}

int main()
{
    Obj o;
    ...
    const char* s1 = objToStr(o);

    char buf[64];
    const char* s2 = objToStr2(o, s2, sizeof(buf));
}
```

Just wondering because objToStr is syntatically must simpler to use and from my basic research there thread local storage in gcc is inlined and shouldn't incur a performance penalty itself.  The only drawback I can think of would be that the cache locality of objToStr2 would be better than the thread local case.

Any other thoughts?

Comment: That's comparing apples and androids. The semantics are different; `objToStr` is not reentrant, and `objToStr2` is.

Comment: Are you seriously concerned about *performance* in this type of code?

Comment: How is it not re-entrant if it's using thread local storage?  Care to elaborate?

Comment: As soon as you are using `snprintf` inside the overhead of `_Thread_local` should completely be negligible.

Comment: @Walter the use of snprintf was for demonstration purposes, what I'm getting at is the use of a passed in char buffer vs thread local char buffer.

Comment: @stgtscc It's not reentrant because it can't be called recursively. Reentrancy is independent from multithreading.

Comment: @molbdnilo yes, at second thought I realize that's correct.  Good point.

Comment: I should close this question as not being constructive

Comment: I think Kerrek meant that `objToStr` is not reentrant because it overwrites the static buffer, whereby destroying previous data and potentially (likely) breaking any code still holding a pointer returned from a previous call.